# Change parameters.yml (database) depending on the domain used

Tags: php, database, parameters, symfony-3.3

I'd like to change som parapeters from parameters.yml depending on the domain that visitor is using to visit me.

In fact, I only need to change the database. If a user comes throw www.domain1.com I need to use the database1 but if he comes throw www.domain2.com I need to use the same code but using database2.

Is it possible?

Comment: So your parameters.yml file will be getting written and rewritten all over the place? Why can't you config your application to figure out the domain for you?

Comment: I don't want to rewrite it exactly. I supouse that at any time symfony goes to read parameters.yml, I just want to catch this moment and pass one or other parameter depending on some condition. An other option could be have different parameters.yml files and make symfony work with one or other dependind on de domain used. Something like config_dev and confing_prod selecting the right confing depending on the domain.

Answer (score 0):

There you have your answer. Just configure another kernel with other parameters like domain. But symfony says:

> Creating aplications with multiple kernels is no longer recommended by
>   Symfony. Consider creating multiple small applications instead.

Read this [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/configuration/multiple_kernels.html)

after that you just need to load in the loader function the files you need taking in account that domain parameter.

Hope it helps

> Edited

You also could read this [another doc](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html) and create a new environment. Think this is better for you.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve is a multi-tenant application.

In your config file, you should create two connections for the database, one for master database which contain you application shared data and the other one which is dynamic and is for tenant specific data.

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection:       default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   "%database_name%"
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
        dynamic_conn:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     "%database_host%"
            port:     "%database_port%"
            dbname:   ~
            user:     "%database_user%"
            password: "%database_password%"
            charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #     path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    default_entity_manager:   default
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection:       default
            mappings:
                MyBundle: ~
        dynamic_em:
            connection:       dynamic_conn
            mappings:
                MyBundle: ~
```

And now you have to set a service for switching database dynamically by listening on request and check the domain,

I suggest you to check this repository, it's an example of what you are trying to achieve https://github.com/uirapuru/multidb.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 3.4 I made it in AppKernel.php

I read domain/subdomain from $_Server['HTTP_HOST'] and then

```
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

    if($subdomain && file_exists($this->getRootDir().'/config/database_'.$subdomain.'.yml')){
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/database_'.$subdomain.'.yml');
    } elseif($subdomain or ($this->getEnvironment() == 'prod' or $this->getEnvironment() == 'dev')) { //php_sapi_name() == "cli"
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/database_default.yml');
    }
```

In config directory, I have files database_domain1.yml, database_domain2.yml etc.